# I want to get the data from my fraba encoder directly to my pc without using PLC

Tags: stm32, ethernet, encoder, data, tcp-ip

The Fraba Encoder which I have is OCD-EEA1B-1213-C10S-PRM Ethernet/IP encoder in which we to get the data from the encoder to show to the PC where we will not use PLC and the communication will be TCP/IP. The current progress is that the encoder is pinging with the PC but we are yet to retrieve the data from the encoder, So is there anyone that can provide assistance, then please do.
https://www.posital.com/en/products/absolute-encoders/absolute-encoder-finder/OCD-EEA1B-1213-C10S-PRM/114134901/detail.php# - link address for encoder details.

Comment: You likely get more responses if you supply a manual link that isn't hidden behind registration requirements on the product's site.

Comment: Half the reason to buy expensive industrial components like this is that you can call the manufacturer and someone knowledgeable will help you. Unless it's Allen Bradley...

Give them a call before you do anything else. If you want us to help, we need a direct link to a datasheet.

Comment: https://www.posital.com/en/products/absolute-encoders/absolute-encoder-finder/OCD-EEA1B-1213-C10S-PRM/114134901/detail.php# - link address for encoder details and datasheet

Comment: But that's not an electrical engineering question. You just need software to form TCP connection to encoder IP address and read data. For testing purposes there are terminal programs, command-line tools, and many programming languages such a Python and C# have libraries that you can try that in approximately 10 lines of code. How does the STM32 tag fit in?